# using pjax for toasts without full refresh

Tags: yii2, pjax

- Pjax for Alerts

There is alert.php included in layout file above $content. This is as below :

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id'=> 'new-alert','enablePushState' => false]); ?>
        <?= \odaialali\yii2toastr\ToastrFlash::widget([
                'options' => [
                    'positionClass' => 'toast-bottom-full-width',
                    //'progressBar' => true,
                    'timeOut' => 6000,
                    'extendedTimeOut' => 2000                       
                ]
         ]);?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

And to get flash messages in ajax , there are calls to below container

```
$.pjax.reload({container:'#new-alert'});
```

This results in showing of alert messages but also sends an Ajax request to URL whichever page is open. Can we trigger request to "/site/toast" on ajax calls which can renderAjax the above widget inplace of making ajax request on current url ?

Since there are no html "a" tag well as neither any "form" tag here inside widget generated html, Is this correct use of pjax ?

```
http://localhost:8081/about-us?_pjax=%23new-alert
```

- Pjax for form

  Also if we wrap an Active Form inside Pjax, how can we make sure that none of A tags or nested Form trigger a Pjax request except the container form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed call for pjax from PHP and made alert as below -

```
<div id="new-alert">

        <?= \odaialali\yii2toastr\ToastrFlash::widget([
                    'options' => [
                        'positionClass' => 'toast-bottom-full-width',
                        //'progressBar' => true,
                        'timeOut' => 6000,
                        'extendedTimeOut' => 2000                       
                    ]
        ]); ?>

</div>
```

Instead I am making pjax call from javascript as below -

```
$.pjax({url: encodeURI(baseUri + "site/toast"), container: '#new-alert', push: false})

public function actionToast() 
{               
    if(Yii::$app->request->getHeaders()->has('X-PJAX'))
    {
        return $this->renderAjax('//common/alert');
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);           
    }
}
```

$.pjax.reload was previously retrieving additional toasts if there were some for current url as well. Above solution only gets toasts related to ajax.